# Need an expensive way to transform a password

Tags: cryptography, webcrypto-api

I'm working on a desktop app using [NeutralinoJS](https://github.com/neutralinojs/neutralinojs) (an Electron alternative).
The app has password authentication for users, but it won't have access to the internet, so the authentication must be done on the client-side.

The data used for authentication is stored in `localStorage` and therefore it can be accessed by anyone who has access to the client PC. So, I can not store passwords as is. I need to transform them using some computationally expensive `webcrypto` method/algorithm.

At first I was thinking to use `digest`

```
const hashToStore = crypto.subtle.digest(algorithm, data)
```

But the digest algorithms are fast and it would be easy to bruteforce the password.

Then I realized I need to generate a key and use `encrypt` method:

```
const key = crypto.subtle.generateKey(algorithm, extractable, keyUsages);
const result = crypto.subtle.encrypt(algorithm, key, data);
```

The problem here is that I need to store generated keys in `localStorage` as well as encrypted password.  Here's the [list of algorithms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/generateKey#parameters).

Which algorithm do I use? Any advice?

Comment: Are you just looking for something like [salting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) and [stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching), or will that not solve your problem?

Comment: @rossum, hey, thank you for the response! The key stretching is very interesting! It seems like it would work for me. Have a nice day!